# I'm having trouble plotting graphs in Python 3.7. How can I do it?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question. I am using Raspiberry Pi 4 python 3.7.

```
value = adc.read(channel=0)
array.append(value)
```

I added the ADC data to the array.
The duration of ADC data is always 50 ms.

So this is how I defined the X-axis for duration:
(How else can I do for more professionel?):

```
xpoints=list(np.array([0,50]))
```

I want to show this in graph.

The X-axis on the chart will be between 0-50.
Y axis will be array values.

Trial 1 worked, no problem;

```
plt.plot(array)
plt.show()
```

Trial 2 worked, no problem;

```
plt.plot(xpoints)
plt.show()
```

But;
Trial 3 did not work. There is problem!!! Graph drawing does not appear on the screen. Why is that?;

```
plt.plot(xpoints,array)
plt.show()
```

Trial 4 worked fine;
Instead of ADC data, I created the y-axis myself;

```
xpoints=list(np.array([0,50]))
ypoints=list(np.array([0,1000]))
plt.plot(xpoints,ypoints)
plt.show()
```

Why isn't Trial 3 working?
Can you help me?

Comment: What is the error? I think your "array" array has not the same shape as "xpoints". Type xpoints.shape and array.shape to check if they have the same shape.

Comment: the length of `xpoints` is 2 - it just just an array with points 0 and 50. How long is the array called `array`? (btw, its best practice not to use key words like "array" for variable names). Unless `array` also only has 2 data points, this is your problem - the two arrays you are trying to plot are different lengths. Perhaps you mean to make `xpoints = np.linspace(0, 50, len(array))` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the commenters' help, I solved the problem by replacing this:

```
xpoints = list(np.array([0, 50]))
```

With this:

```
xpoints = np.linspace(0, 50, len(array))
```